# Find minimums with R (1 Variable X, n times a fixed parameter U)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, optimization, minimum

I'm trying to minimize a function f(X,U) = (X*log(X)-1/(1-U))^2
where U=(U_1,...,U_n) ~ U(0,1), that means I have n amount of fixed U's and want to find the min of:

```
(x_1*ln(x_1)-1/(1-u_1))^2
(x_2*ln(x_2)-1/(1-u_2))^2
......
(x_n*ln(x_n)-1/(1-u_n))^2
```

For that, I wanted to use the optim function.

I have defined:

```
n <- 10^3 
U <- sort(runif(n,min=0,max=1)) 
X <- c()
Xsolution<- c()

f <- function(X,U){
 return(-(X*log(X)-(1/(1-U)))^2)
}  #-, because min(f) = max(-f)
```

now I have no idea how to do this with optim()? I always get the following error for the following code:

```
for(i in 1:n){
    Xsolution[i] <- optim(f(X,U[i])
}
```

Error in log(X) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

---

### Sidenote: I would welcome a method without a for-loop, since for great n, it will take too long. Maybe you can help me get it work with sapply? Or an alternative way?

Alternatively, I thought I got it working with optimize(...,maximize=FALSE,..):

```
f <- function (X, a) ((X*log(X)-(1/(1-a)))^2)

for (i in 1:n){
  xmin[i] <- optimize(f, c(0, 10000), tol = 0.0001, a = U[i])
}
```

This doesn't work either properly...

Also, the problem may be that it will take tooooo long. I want to do it with n=10^6. But I'm quite sure there has to be a way doing it without a for-loop? I think the for-loop is the problem that makes this take ages. Please help me, I've been sitting on this problem for ages and it's quite frustrating.

Comment: True, all entries of xmin were equal. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with the problem? 

I have a vector U = (u1,...un) where the u's are fixed and I want the solution for the equations

x1*log(x1) - 1/(1-u1) and this for all u_i in U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `X * log(X) = 1 / (1 - U[i])` can be solved numerically for any `U[i]`, there is a solution for each distinct `U[i]` so any of the `(X*ln(X)-1/(1-U[i]))^2` can be driven to zero and therefore there is a solution for each distinct U[i].   If typically the U[i] are all distinct that means there are length(U) solutions.  The solutions are given by (can omit the unique if the U[i] are all distinct):

```
f <- function (X, a) ((X*log(X)-(1/(1-a)))^2)
unique(sapply(U, function(a) optimize(f, c(0, 1000000), a = a)$minimum))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had also solved it with the for-loop this way:

`xmin <- c()

f <- function (x, a) (x*log(x)-(1/(1-a)))^2

for(i in 1:n){
  xmin[i] <- optimize(f, c(0, 10^10), tol = 0.0001, a=U[i])$minimum
}`

Currently, I'm looking which one is faster. Thanks!

Comment: I would think that the optimization is what takes the time and whether you use `sapply` or `for` will not make a lot of difference.

Comment: I made a few tests: for loop took between 22 and 26 minutes for 10^6 data and the same function above and sapply took between 4 and 8 minutes.

Comment: If you preallocate the result vector rather than incrementally expanding it the loop will run a lot faster.